# How I can use a converter in a JSF tag selectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, converters, selectonemenu

The following example works in my interface:

```
<h:outputText value="#{diplome.pays}">
    <gn:converter origine="#{config.origManSirhen}"
                  nomenclature="#{config.codePays}"
                  propriete="libelleImpression" />
</h:outputText>
```

However, when I try to use the same converter does not work when the element is a [selectOneMenu](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/selectOneMenu.html)

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="pays">
    <f:selectItem
        itemValue="#{InformationsPersonnellesModele.adressePrincipale.pays}"
        itemLabel="#{InformationsPersonnellesModele.adressePrincipale.pays}" />
    <gn:converter origine="#{config.origManSirhen}"
        nomenclature="#{config.codePays}" propriete="libelleImpression" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I have tried to use the attribute `converter` into the `selectOneMenu` tag, but it does not work as I expect because I need to use as well the parameter nomenclature and propiete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution:

The item selected by default must be the value of the [selectOneMenu](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/selectOneMenu.html) tag.

And the list of items and the converter are directly assigned to the value of the [selectItems](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/selectItems.html) tag.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="pays"
    value="#{InformationsPersonnellesModele.adressePrincipale.pays}">
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{gnl:listeTri(config.origManSirhen, config.codePays,'libelleImpression')}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```